# MySQL using a custom string comparison operator in Index

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, innodb, mariadb

I am looking for a way to specify the order used by a MySQL index (BTREE in InnoDB using MariaDB 10). More specifically I would like to create an index which indexes a `varchar` column with variable length entries similar to the following pseudo-code:

```
-- assume "str" to be the field in question, return values like strcmp
if (len(row1.str) < len(row2.str))
{
    return -1;
} else if (len(row1.str) > len(row2.str)) {
    return 1;
} else {
    return row1.str < row2.str;
}
```

Is there a way to specify this ordering for one particular index only?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should have the same effect:

```
ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(str), str
```

Comment: I have considered using a materialized view with a similar `ORDER BY` clause, but that would have to be used (read joined) explicitly in queries on the db, whereas having an index would just enable the query optimizer to choose it when appropriate I think.

Answer (score 1):

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/virtual-computed-columns/ --

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN
  for_sorting VARCHAR(...)   -- make a little wider than `str`
      AS (       -- syntax
         CONCAT(
            RIGHT(CONCAT('0000', CHAR_LENGTH(str)), 5),  -- num sortable as string
               ':', str )  -- tack on `str` for when len differs
      ) PERSISTENT   -- "indexes can only be based on PERSISTENT virtual columns"
      COMMENT "kludge for special indexing"
```

Then do `ORDER BY for_sorting`.

(Caveat:  I have not tried it, but it feels like it will work.)

Comment: [In]compatibility note:  This is MariaDB-specific feature; MySQL has something equivalent.

Comment: Also a good idea, but takes n + log(n) + some constant additional space for a string of length n. In the end I went with a conversion to an integer value for a subset of the possible inputs, and a hard error for unexpected values.

Comment: Since it is `PERSISTENT`, the expression is evaluated once per `INSERT` (or `UPDATE`); this is minor overhead.  Once it "persists", the overhead for `ORDER BY` is the same as using any other column for sorting.  Yes, it does take extra disk space, equivalent to adding a column and indexing the new column.